# Using eq_ with nose tests, is there a way to know which line # and position # two strings differ?

Tags: python, pycharm, nosetests

Coming from some other technologies, there have been string comparison assertions for use in unit tests that show string 1 on one line (in the console output) and string 2 on the second line, and clue you to what position # is the first difference (when there is a difference).

I think I can write a helper easily enough to accomplish this but thought I'd check if something like this exists before re-inventing a wheel.  Right now I'm using eq_ and (at least within PyCharm) it isn't useful in revealing where the difference is when long and/or multi-line strings are involved.

Is there something more useful than eq_ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using `unittest` with `nose`, you are probably looking for [`unittest.TestCase.assertMultilineEqual`](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertMultiLineEqual).